# Sonar 3.2 starting error: We're sorry, but something went wrong

Tags: sonarqube

When i try start Sonar 3.2 (i know it's an old version, but it's for testing purposes) it won't start. The only message is 'We're sorry, but something went wrong.'

I think it's problem with the db, but Sonar with the same db is up and running. I don't get it.

part of sonar.log

```
...
2013.09.06 15:53:12 INFO  o.s.s.p.ServerImpl  Sonar Server / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:12 INFO  o.s.c.p.Database  Create JDBC datasource to url jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://172.30.71.139;databaseName=SONARPROD22;SelectMethod=Cursor
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem  Sonar home: /opt/sonar-3.2
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem  Deploy dir: /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/deploy
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Install plugins...
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Findbugs / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin JaCoCo / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin English Pack / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Surefire / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Duplications / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Checkstyle / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin PMD / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Java / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Core / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Database Cleaner / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Squid for Java / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Cobertura / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Email notifications / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Design / 3.2 / d9303b2d9d4c1e75f8536e4144028f1999f727f4
2013.09.06 15:53:13 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Install plugins done: 245 ms
2013.09.06 15:53:14 INFO  o.s.s.p.ApplicationDeployer  Deploy Ruby on Rails applications
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 15:53:25 | JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 15:53:25 | gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 15:53:36 | 2013-09-06 15:53:36.073:WARN:/:unable to create shared application instance
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 15:53:36 | org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: no connection available|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:61:in `initialize'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:31:in `initialize'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:6:in `jdbc_connection'|?from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2056:in `send'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'|?from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1418:in `loop'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'|?from file:/opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.1.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb:435:in `initialize'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb:400:in `up'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:63:in `upgrade_and_start'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:75:in `automatic_setup'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:131:in `(root)'|?from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1063:in `load'|?from /opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:53:in `load_environment'|?from file:/opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.0.1.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:46:in `to_app'|?from file:/opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.0.1.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:191:in `new'|?from <script>:2:in `(root)'|?from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2021:in `instance_eval'|?from file:/opt/sonar-3.2/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.0.1.jar!/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'|?from <script>:2:in `(root)'|
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 15:53:36 |       at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$4.init(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:184)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 15:53:36 |       at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.getApplication(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:59)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 15:53:36 |       at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.init(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:27)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 15:53:36 |       at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:40)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 15:53:36 |       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 15:53:36 |       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 15:53:36 |       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1272)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 15:53:36 |       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 15:53:36 |       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489)
...
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

With kind regards

Comment: Server fails to connect to database. You should check connectivity to jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://172.30.71.139;databaseName=SONARPROD22 with the given credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the service instead of batch script and make sure that you have sonar.username and sonar.password properties set to what is available in your MYSQL db.